# How correct install R keras using Linux Debian

Tags: r, tensorflow, ubuntu, keras

I have virtual debian server. Namely

```
braingen@vm-mob:~$ Linux vm-mob 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64
```

i have installed r-base-core

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
R
```

when in R console i try install keras

```
install.packages("keras")
```

When i do it this i get trouble

```
he downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpxmyvE9/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘reticulate’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘tfautograph’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘tfruns’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘tensorflow’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘keras’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

So of course i can't load library.

How can i correct install keras and dependency?
Thank you

The full log

```
> install.packages("keras")
Installing package into ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘png’, ‘tfautograph’, ‘reticulate’, ‘tensorflow’, ‘tfruns’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2941808 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/png_0.1-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24990 bytes (24 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 24 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tfautograph_0.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46883 bytes (45 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 45 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/reticulate_1.20.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 832951 bytes (813 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 813 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tensorflow_2.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46786 bytes (45 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 45 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tfruns_1.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2011046 bytes (1.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/keras_2.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3462992 bytes (3.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
 package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 libs
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api.cpp -o api.o
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:171: api.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp’
* installing *source* package ‘png’ ...
 package ‘png’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      libpng-config --cflags -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read.c -o read.o
/bin/bash: libpng-config: command not found
read.c:3:10: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
 #include <png.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:162: read.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘png’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/png’
ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘png’ are not available for package ‘reticulate’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/reticulate’
ERROR: dependency ‘reticulate’ is not available for package ‘tfautograph’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tfautograph’
ERROR: dependency ‘reticulate’ is not available for package ‘tfruns’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tfruns’
ERROR: dependencies ‘reticulate’, ‘tfruns’, ‘tfautograph’ are not available for package ‘tensorflow’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tensorflow’
ERROR: dependencies ‘reticulate’, ‘tensorflow’, ‘tfruns’ are not available for package ‘keras’
* removing ‘/home/braingen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/keras’

Brain gen, [25.08.21 13:53]
The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpxmyvE9/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘reticulate’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘tfautograph’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘tfruns’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘tensorflow’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("keras") :
  installation of package ‘keras’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Comment: Looks like there's no `g++` installed, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50729550/6574038

Comment: Do follow the instructions mentioned here https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the 'png' package failed to install because of a missing system header. I tried in a docker container but was not able to reproduce your error locally. Two ideas:
a) perhaps there is some additional system dependency required that isn't included with the debian image you are using? Maybe something like `apt install png-dev` would make it work.

b) Maybe update the version of R? R 3.5 was released over 3 years ago, and that might be the root cause of the issue, and the current release version of R is 4.1.1.

Comment: Also note that you can satisfy this via `sudo apt install r-cran-rcpp r-cran-png` and rely on the pre-made binaries.  Same for ~ 1000 other CRAN packages in current Debian.  As for the R 3.5 -- yikes.  See https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/ for a simple alternative of getting _current_ R while staying on your Debian release.